# Change FAB (Floating Action Button) srcCompat using java

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, floating-action-button

I an using a Floating Action Button with a set icon using XML

```
app:srcCompat="@mipmap/my_image"
```

I want to use java so that if a certain condition is true, the FAB's icon can change to something like `my_image2`

I have declared my FAB in my java class, but how do I change the icon? Thanks.

Comment: You should be able to change the `setImageResource` - https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/FloatingActionButton.html#setImageResource(int)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Per the [FloatingActionButton documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/FloatingActionButton.html):

> As this class descends from [ImageView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html), you can control the icon which is displayed via [setImageDrawable(Drawable)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setImageDrawable(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable)).

You can, of course, use any of the `setImage` variants, such as [setImageResource](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setImageResource(int)) if you have a resource id.

Comment: How do you initialize the image `@mipmap/my_image` to use it as a Drawable?

Comment: You'd want to use `setImageResource(R.mipmap.my_image)`